# アノテーションを使用したルーティングの使いどころ・利点がわかりません

Tags: symfony2, url-routing

[【Symfony2】RoutingはAnnotationで記述すると管理が楽になる！ | ゆとりっち](http://www.starlod.net/symfony2-routing-annotation.html)

このページを参考に、アノテーションを使ったルーティングの記述についてはある程度理解できました。

しかしこの機能をどのように使えば、何のメリットがあるかがわかりません。

例えば会員登録のようなコントローラを書くとして、この方法でルーティングを記述する利点はどこにあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「アノテーションを使用したルーティング」で連想されるのは、コントローラに `@Route("/")` といったコメントでルートを定義する方法で、ご指摘のページにはほとんど記載がないように思うのですが、この話であっているでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。申し訳ございません、提示したサイトを間違えていました。正しくは、http://www.starlod.net/symfony2-routing-annotation.htmlです。申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。そのサイトを見て記述方法はわかったが、アノテーションを使用したルーティングの使いどころ・メリットがよくわからない、ということでしょうか。記述方法についてもまだよくわかっていませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。はい、その通り「アノテーションを使用したルーティングの使いどころ・メリットがよくわからない」です。例えば、会員登録のようなコントローラが存在したとして、何に使うのだろう？何のメリットがあるのだろう？と思います（そもそも私の想像が的外れかも知れませんが・・・）。アノテーションを使用したルーティングの記述方法はある程度理解出来ていると思います。

Comment: そのことを前面に出すようにタイトルと本文を書き換えてみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かに分かりやすいですね、、、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/config/routing.yml かアノテーションをどちらを選ぶかは、好みや慣れの問題だと思います。

それぞれのメリットは前者が俯瞰的に把握しやすく、後者はアクションとの対応関係が一目で把握しやすいことです。

アノテーションの表記に対して違和感や拒絶感が強く、思考停止して、作業が進まないというのであれば、無理をして使う必要はないと思います。

ルートの一覧は app/console から調べることができます。

```
php app/console debug:router
```

「会員登録」ということばの意味が Security コンポーネントによるユーザー認証と認可に該当するのであれば、ルーティング (@Route) とは異なる別のアノテーションが用意されています (@Security)。ユーザー認証と認可に関する設定ファイルは app/config/security.yml です。

次の index アクションでは ROLE_ADMIN のロールをもったユーザーしかアクセスできないようになっています。

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * @Route("/hello/{firstName}/{lastName}", name="homepage_hello")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */

public function indexAction($firstName, $lastName)
{
}
```

Security コンポーネントのマニュアルを読んでも、すぐに手が動かないかもしれませんので、些細なことでもわからないことがあったら、一人で悩まずに気軽に質問するとよいでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。マニュアル（docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/book/page_creation.html）を読み進んでいくうちに少しずつ理解できるようになりました。今回の質問はユーザ認証ではなく単に会員データを登録する仕様を考えていたので例としてデータの登録を挙げたまででした。紛らわしくてすみません。しかしながら今担当している案件でユーザの認証・認可も必要になるので、これはこれで助かります。ありがとうございました。